# TextView expanding with respect to text

Tags: android

My activity has the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_guide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="media.ubique.heterotopia.Guide">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guide_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guide_story"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/guide_title" />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/back_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/guide_story" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then I update the content of the `TextView` from my activity dynamically with a text excerpt that is too large to fit a single screen. The resulting app only shows part of the text - the button in the end is not displayed at all. What I want is a screen that scrolls so that the whole content is there. I tried encapsulating content in this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <!--.....-->
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

with no luck - I do get scrolling but still the `TextView` only displays part of the text.

Comment: Post whole code with your scrollView implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/activity_guide"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="media.ubique.heterotopia.Guide">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guide_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guide_story"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
    android:text="@string/back_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `orientation="vertical"` to the LinearLayout.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!--.....-->
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with vertical orientation inside a ScrollView instead of RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_guide"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="media.ubique.heterotopia.Guide">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_padding="10dp"
    android:margin_bottom="50dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guide_story"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:text="@string/back_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply reduce the size of text dynamically.
or here is working sample for you.Modify this according to your requirement.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    >

                   //add here

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    >

                 //add here
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    >


               //add here
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```